# buttonType property of subclassed UIButton is cannot be changed in IB

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uibutton

title of question explains all, I subclassed UIButton and I'm using that in Interface Builder.

I set buttonType UIButtonTypeRoundRect, but it only works as UIButtonTypeCustom.

I think buttonType property is different from other properties, it is read-only and it can be decided when button is created.

Anyone know how does it work below of water?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the class in IB to your subclass?

Yes, I believe you are right, it looks only settable at creation time. Regardless, seems like you should be able to subclass and have IB set the button type and have your subclass get instantiated and work.

Comment: yes, of course I did, but the only problem is I can't change button type via IB, it works as only UIButtonTypeCustom. I want to know is there any benefit under water, how does it works.